# Return mongoose result in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm trying to return a result from my mongoose find operation. I know a lot of question have already been asked for this but i think this is different. Here's my user :

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    variable: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Variable'}
});
```

My user have a method to retrieve his variable. Here's the problem.

```
UserSchema.methods.getVariable = function()  {
   //TODO ?
}
```

I don't know how to populate my field and then return the result of the populate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate)

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  variable: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Variable'}
});

UserSchema.
  findOne({your:"query"}).
  populate('variable').
  exec().
  then(
    user=>console.log("user is:",user)
  );
```

Comment: That's what i did first but i need to return the value i obtain.

Comment: @JérémyMisiti What do you think `user=>console.log("user is:",user)` is?

Comment: I didn't saw the Arrow sorry ! So this will work when i call my user like :
`user.getVariable()` ? :o

Comment: @JérémyMisiti not sure why you would do that. You can query for users with populate and on the result do: `user.variable`

Comment: To get my variables. eg : `if (user.getVariable("var name").value == "true")`